# Concatenar datos y hacer insert en un campo

Tags: php, sql

Tengo parte de este código `php`, donde se esta haciendo un `insert` a la tabla `inventory_list`, pero lo que necesito es que depende de que haya seleccionado en `fkCategory`,`fkLocation` y `fkSubCat` que hacen referencia al `id` del dato.

Seleccione `name_category` de la tabla `category`, `name_sub` de la tabla `sub_category` y `numFile` que es el nuevo id autoincrementable que se genero al hacerse el insert, obtener estos datos y concatenarlos de esta manera:

```
c.name_category+ "00"+ idSub + "00"+ numFile
```

Quedaria de esta manera:

```
CON-006-003
```

Y que se inserte en el campo `id_item`

Este es el `codigo` `php`:

```
    $query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_list 
    (id_item,description_item,price_item,
    manufacturer,model_item,
    reorder_Level,target_Stock,image,registerDate,commentt,
    fkEngineer,fkCategory,fkLocation,fkSupplier,fkUnit,fkSubCat)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';

 $query2="SELECT c.name_category,sc.idSub,i.numFile 
    from inventory_list
    inner join category as c on id_category =fkCategory
    inner join sub_category as sc on idSub =fkSubCat where numFile = ?"
    //guardar datos
    //insert en campo id_item -> c.name_category+ "00"+ idSub + "00"+ numFile


    $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['id_item'], $_POST['description_item'], 
    $_POST['price_item'] ,$_POST['manufacturer'],
    $_POST['model_item'], $_POST['reorder_Level'],
    $_POST['target_Stock'], $_POST['imageName'],
    $hoy, $_POST['commentt'] ,$_POST['fkEngineer'],
    $_POST['fkCategory'],$_POST['fkLocation'],
    $_POST['fkSupplier'],$_POST['fkUnit'],
    $_POST['fkSubCat']));
    if ($result > 0)
     {....}
```

Como podria lograrlo?

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entiendo bien. Lo que necesitas es insertar un dato "calculado" en el que parte de la concatenación se utiliza el "ID" del registro que estás insertando, ¿es así?.

Si es esa la necesidad, puedes utilizar "computed columns" cuya definición depende del motor de BD que estés utilizando, por ejemplo, si fuera Sql Server (también existen en MySql, y otros manejadores), puede utilizarse:

```
CREATE TABLE Datos   
(  
    Id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL  
  , Valor smallint  
  , Codigo AS 'DAT-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Id)  
);  

INSERT INTO dbo.Datos (Valor)  
VALUES (10), (20);  

SELECT * FROM Datos


Id     Valor     Codigo    
 -----  --------  --------- 
 1      10        DAT-1     
 2      20        DAT-2
```

Espero sea eso, si no, creo que debes aclarar un poco más tu pregunta.

Comment: fkCategory y demas fk que estan en la tabla inventory_list, son foráneas de las respectivas tablas, y obvio solo se guarda el id haciendo referencia al dato seleccionado ya que este se define a través de un select en un formulario.

Lo que necesito es que antes de que se inserte, obtener los datos como el name_category y demas, concatenar y hacer el insert al campo.

Comment: Creo entonces, que puedes utilizar las columnas calculadas (computed columns) que menciono, con un "insert select": https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp